# Mobile keyboard turn off input autosuggestion

Tags: ionic-framework, input, ionic2, hide, autosuggest

how can I turn off autosuggestion strip above the mobile keyboard in Ionic?

I've already tried:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"
class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your user name" 
value="" 
autocapitalize="off" 
autocomplete="off"
spellcheck="false" 
autocorrect="off"   />
```

but none of these works.
The same problem persists for `<ion-input>`.

[image: Screenshot of unwanted strip]

Comment: I think that is the keyboard app feature rather than ionic/your app... User probably has to turn it off in their keyboard setting